# Why is the focus being lost here and how to fix that

Tags: c++, qt

Look at this short program.
It shows a normal image inside a QDialog and after a click, the image goes fullscreen and stretched. However, when the control is returned back to the dialog (with another click), the focus is lost and I don't know how to get it back.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

#define  PATH2IMG "<path to your image>"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QDialog      dlg;
    QVBoxLayout  vbl;
    QPushButton  btn;
    QPixmap      pxm;
    QSize        siz;
    auto         fun=[&](QSize s) {
        btn.setIcon(QIcon(pxm.scaled(s,Qt::AspectRatioMode::KeepAspectRatio)));
        btn.setIconSize(s);
    };

    vbl.addWidget(&btn);
    btn.setFlat(true);
    btn.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::ApplicationModal);
    pxm.load(PATH2IMG);
    siz=btn.size();
    fun(siz);

    QObject::connect(
        &btn,
        &QPushButton::clicked,
        [&]() {
            if(btn.isFullScreen()) {
                vbl.addWidget(&btn);
                fun(siz);
                //btn.activateWindow(); // Edited (2023-11-08); Disabled (2023-11-09)
                //btn.showNormal();     // Edited (2023-11-08); Disabled (2023-11-09)
                QTimer::singleShot(
                    0,
                    [&]() {
                        dlg.activateWindow();
                    }
                ); // Edited (2023-11-09)
            }
            else {
                vbl.removeWidget(&btn);
                btn.setParent(nullptr);
                btn.showFullScreen();
                fun(btn.size());
            }
        }
    );

    dlg.setLayout(&vbl);
    dlg.setWindowTitle("Click on the image");
    app.exit(dlg.exec());
}
```

Replace the content of PATH2IMG with the path to some medium-size image.

For simplicity, I've used a button to hold the image.

I've tried with `setFocus()` and `setFocusPolicy()` but no success.

Any hint?

---

**Edit (2023-11-08)**:

Thanks to @musicamante, the use of activateWindow() restores the focus, and by just pressing Enter, it's possible to go fullscreen again.

Pressing space does not work after returning from fullscreen. So I had to add a call to showNormal() for this to work as expected.

Honestly, I don't know about the logic behind of this. A simple setFocus() instead of those two lines should work.

Maybe this weird behavior is caused by orphaning the button before going fullscreen.

---

**Edit (2023-11-09)**:

Thanks again to @musicamante for the follow up.

Still no idea about why setFocus() does not work in this case, but the new approach makes more sense than the previous one.

Comment: Have you tried calling [QApplication::focusWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#focusWidget) to figure out where focus went?

Comment: @JarMan Yes, to the QDialog. But that does not behave correctly.

Comment: What focus is lost, that of the button or that of the window? When the button is clicked from full screen, does the dialog get activated? It's also important to know *when* you tried to call `setFocus()` and on what target.

Comment: @musicamante The whole application loses the focus. In Windows, it blinks in the task bar. And programmatically, it says that the focused widget is the dialog. But a click is required to set the real focus. The dialog is returned back to its previous state and visible. Activated? I don't think so.
And I've tried `setFocus()` in many places. The logical placement is after `fun(siz)`, in the `clicked()` slot.

Comment: Then try to use `activateWindow()` after reparenting the button. Note that setting the `iconSize` equal to the button size is *wrong*, as it will make the button expand its size considering the QStyle margins; you should at least subtract the `PM_ButtonMargin` and the `PM_DefaultFrameWidth` (twice).

Comment: @musicamante OK. Will try that. Don't pay much attention to how the image is shown. This was only to have a tiny reproductible sample. The actual program is using a graphics view/scene for this, etc.

Comment: @Alvein Ok, but I wasn't talking about the image appearance: the problem is about widget size; it may not be a relevant problem for this case, but it's very important to consider: setting the `iconSize()` of a button alters its size hint (most importantly, the `minimumSizeHint()`, which will cause the button to *become* larger in order to properly show the icon at the given size. For instance, in the rare case you wanted to change the icon size in a `resizeEvent()`, you'll end up with infinite recursion if you use the new size as the icon size.

Comment: @musicamante `activateWindow()` partially solved the problem. I don't need more than that, but for the particular example, the button can get the focus again after returning from fullscreen.

Comment: @Alvein I know that the button is just an example, my point was about *general usage*, not specific to this case. In any case, what do you mean by "partially solved the problem"? Please try to be more specific when you explain your problems, their context, and also your attempts (for instance, inowing exactly how you tried to use `setFocus()` and `setFocusPolicy()` would allow us to *focus* on those attempts and eventually explaining you what was possibly wrong with them, which is more useful to you than just telling how to do things).

Comment: @Alvein If you fixed it, it'd be good to write a short answer, like just showing the line(s) you added and telling where exactly you added them.

Comment: @Alvein Calling `btn.activateWindow()` is probably incorrect: I don't remember the full widget/layout reparent implementation (it's quite complex, as it also follows some OS specific aspects that may need event queuing), but since it uses the `windowHandle()` activation, it may not be enough: at that point, the widget may not have a valid QWindow yet. A proper solution would probably be to use a `QTimer.singleShot(0, dlg.activateWindow)` that activates the *real* window (possibly with `interval`>0). The `showNormal()` may not be required, but it certainly has to happen *before* all that.

Comment: @Alvein Also note: 1. when `clicked` is emitted, the mouse/key release event is still existing within the event loop of the application, and it *may* be processed in some way furthermore; 2. the `Enter` key may work differently if the button has the default mode set (which is implicit for buttons that are children QDialog, depending on the situation, based on buttons that are its children and the object tree hierarchy): it triggers the clicked event on the *assumed* default button just on `Enter` key *press*, not on its *release*. That's why it may be important to delay `dlg.activateWindow()`.